# WHM Module Installer - Why is SOAP not showing in phpinfo?

Tags: soap, whm

I'm trying to install SOAP on server. This is what I did:

1. Got into WHM Module Installers
2. Installed SOAP 0.13.0
3. Confirmed it was there; looked in FTP and I see the SOAP directory created
4. Restarted server  Added phpinfo on server and went to it on browser
5. Also added extension = php_soap.so on php settings Didn't see SOAP on phpinfo

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved. After installing the application on module installers in WHM, need to go to EasyApache and add SOAP in the exhaustive list and build it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer submitted by @kakenx , follow the steps to enable extension with EasyApache

- Login to WHM control panel
- Select EasyApache from left nav
- On EasyApache, click on the gear icon on default profile under Previously Saved Config section.
- Add SOAP extension in Exhaustive Options List.
- Click Save and Build
- Click Recompile and wait for the compilation process
- After done with everything, restart Apache

[Reference Link](http://www.linglom.com/administration/enable-php-extensions-with-easyapache-on-whm-cpanel)

Answer (score 0):

What @saiid mentioned worked 100% been looking and doing SUDO's for over 2 hours turns out its just a whm easyapche setting...

just in 2022 its
whm -> easyapche4 -> Currently Installed Packages (Click customize)
-> PHP Extensions (search soap)
enable both php74-php-soap & php80-php-soap
next then follow steps to provision.

boom bobs your uncle works like a charm. |

Edit
no restard required can if you using woocommerce youll notice its enabled under status